# How to store email sender info in message field using email contact module?

Tags: 7, emails

I am using email and email contact module. I added the field as following:
[image]

Front page displays as following:
[image]

When anonymous users enter name, email, subject and message, it sends email to recipient. However, recipient only gets the message from the Message field. recipient does not get any info on name, email, and subject.

I clicked the gear icon and i see the following:
[image]

Do I need to enter some token in the email body? If so, I have been struggling and not able to find out what tokens will go into the email body field so receipient will receive all the info.

---

In email body, I entered these:

> 1[current-user:name] 2 [site:mail] 3 [site:name]  4[current-user:mail]
>   5 [current-page:url].

In front page, I entered these:

> Name: john doe  Email: johnd@gmaidl.com    Subject:quote  Message:
>   messsage body.

Recipient received these:

> 1Anonymous 2 admin email 3 e-Shop | e-News 4 5 page URL
>
> message body

How can recipient gets what anonymouse user entered?

Comment: It is about Drupal 7